# Accessing Data's from mutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've an mutable array { arrayname == colA } with 16 objects, i want access these elements individually and want to put it in a label in a tableviewcell, i've done all and am able to access data, but at last it shows an error like "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException"...

Code I've done is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      EasyTamilTeacherTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
          easyTamil = [colA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          cell.inputLabel.text = easyTamil;
      }
      return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show the ENTIERE error message. I don't understand the `for loop`.

Comment: Show the error message fully.

Comment: colA seems to contain arrays itself, but your error message suggest that it doesn't contain enough elements.

Comment: Your loop doesn't make sense, you are just replacing the inputLabel's text over and over again.

Comment: yup, there is no need of loop here, now i can able to sort out the pbm, thanks guys

Comment: You completely changed the type of question and the types of variables. If you have a fix, it would be better to post as an answer than to turn the question into a different one.

Answer (score 2):

Quite basic :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EasyTamilTeacherTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];  
// Other cell settings  

 cell.inputLabel.text= [colA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to add manually subview to a `UITableViewCell` since they are reused. Plus, if it's already a custom `UITableViewCell`, it should have a label property.

Comment: @Larme : Agree. Edited the answer.

Comment: This is a complete different logic than what @Muthukumar does. You are setting the text to an array.

Comment: @Eiko : I think the user actually wants to display some property from the array element on the label. Loop is not at all necessary. He is first running the loop and then again using index path.row on it.

Comment: @Nitish Seems he is iterating over all columns for the concrete row (which looks like odd but valid). Replacing the text over and over again is fishy, though. But the point is: if colA[i] was a string, as you assume, I'd expect his code to either not compile properly (with type checks) or crash with an unrecognized selector for objectAtIndex:. But he's getting NSRangeException, which indicates it's indeed an array he's working on.

Comment: @Eiko : Check Muthukumar answer. As per him areay has strings as objects. So just as a replacement to my answer, object should be string.

Comment: Yes, now he changed the question a lot, and your answer makes sense.

Comment: @Nitish Sure, but that edit was needed, because the voting was locked already.

Comment: @Eiko : I understand :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for the datasource method return the number of row in section properly. it should return the count of datasource items.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return colA.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        EasyTamilTeacherTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        easyTamil = colA[indexPath.row];
        cell.inputLabel.text=easyTamil;
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like array had strings as objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding `NSSString` in `NSMutableArray`.
If you are storing your string in an object and adding that object in `NSMutableArray`, then

```
object = [colA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // return you object
```

get string value from `object` and pass it to label.

```
cell.inputLabel.text = object.myLabel;
```

Please add error message in the question. It will be easy for us to give you correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

kindly try

1. Casting data model (if data model is there) else check key=>value
   exist which you want to access
2. check value is valid. try using if let for ensuring value is there before setting it to label

   ```
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
   let array : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: [NSDictionary()])
   if array.count > indexPath.row{
       if let dictionary = array[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
           if let name = dictionary.valueForKey("KeyDoesn't Exist") as? String{
               print("name == >>", name)
               //set name
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: **if array.count > indexPath.row**

will resolved issue of NSRangeException, which will occur while trying to access object at out-of array boundry.

Answer (score 0):

**Note : -** There are two UITableView delegate methods are used, Don't forget to bind Datasource and Delegate.

**After that apply this** :- 
@interface SecondVC : UIViewController<
UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


return mutArrMessages.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblMessage.text = mutArrMessages[indexPath.row]
return cell;
}
```